# python multiply two lists element wise - one of them is nested

Tags: python, list, nested

I have two lists:

```
C = [3, 2, 1]
D = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]
```

I would like to achieve this result:

```
E = [[0, 3, 6, 9], [0, 2, 4], [0, 1]]
```

using only list comprehensions.Is it possible ? I am stuck at:

```
E = zip(C, D)
[i * E[0][0] for i in E[0][1]] which gives:

[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

but I cannot modify it to apply for other elements of the second list

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible:

```
>>> [[c * d_i for d_i in d] for c, d in zip(C, D)]
[[0, 3, 6, 9], [0, 2, 4], [0, 1]]
```

You just need two loops here, the first one to iterate over `zip(C, D)`, and the second one to iterate over each list of `D`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there: it's a nested list comprehension.  Slap another list, [blah[j] for j in ]

```
C = [3, 2, 1]
D = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]

E = zip(C, D)
print [[i * E[j][0] for i in E[j][1]] for j in range(len(E))]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3, 6, 9], [0, 2, 4], [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be straight forward if you use `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(C) * np.array(map(np.array, D))

# array([array([0, 3, 6, 9]), array([0, 2, 4]), array([0, 1])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also solve it with [`itertools.startmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>>
>>> def multiply(x, lst):
        return [x*i for i in lst]

>>> for item in it.starmap(f, zip(C,D)):
        print(item)


[0, 3, 6, 9]
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 1]
```

OR:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for item in it.starmap(lambda x,y: [x*i for i in y], zip(C,D)):
        l.append(item)
>>> l
[[0, 3, 6, 9], [0, 2, 4], [0, 1]]
```